# Stack or WordPress-Stack?

Tags: discussion

I am planning to become more active on the Stack Exchange. I know stuff about PHP and WordPress. What questions should be asked on Stack Overflow and which should be asked on the WordPress-stack? I don't have a ton of questions right now, but I'm curious as to where the rules have been drawn.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts on this already. I believe Jan Fabry and mario to be correct on this issue, that wordpress related questions should START on the wordpress SE however be moved to SO if they are deemed more algorithmic than wordpress related. Going to leave this open for a bit to see if anyone has anything else to add.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/faq

> WordPress - Stack Exchange is for WordPress **developers and administrators**. If your question generally covers the operation of websites which you control, then you're in the right place to ask your question!

So by that, even programming questions are on-topic on WordPress SE. Though you should differentiate. If you have an algorithmic problem, then ask on Stackoverflow first. If you are writing some plugin which depends on deeper knowledge of the WordPress Core API, then SO is often a suboptimal place to ask.

There are more WordPress experts on WP SE than on SO. And Wordpress questions seemingly go stale on SO sometimes.

Answer (score 4):

Stack Overflow is for general programming questions.

The Wordpress site is for both Wordpress programming and operational questions (I should have double checked the [faq](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/faq)).

So while you could ask a development question on Stack Overflow if it deals with the intricacies of Wordpress then it should probably be asked on the Wordpress site.

More general programming questions - Stack Overflow.

Specific programming questions and operational issues - Wordpress.

Comment: I am involved in the WP Stack Exchange, and I think we should be *the* starting place for all WordPress-related questions. Otherwise it will be too confusing to delineate the "territories" of each site. Indeed, this will mean that SO will get less WordPress-related questions, but I don't think that would be a bad thing: the WP-questions are a minuscule fraction of SO. Notice I said *starting place*: so for your Twitter-question we would answer how to interface with the WordPress plugin API, for the Twitter API-part you would be referred to WebApps or SO.

Comment: @Jan - I've reworked my answer. My fault for not double checking the FAQ before posting.

Comment: No problem, and we're still debating the scope (well we *should be*, the discussion seemed to wind down), so it's possible that the FAQ can change. But my core idea is that a site should be the starting place for its subject, so if there is a SE site for anything related to your question, you should look there first.

Comment: @Jan - that makes sense. I did sign up to the Wordpress site (I host my own Wordpress blog) but never got involved.